# How to put design in Excel spreadsheet/s using VB6

Tags: excel, vb6

How can i put some design in excel spreadsheets? like the photo below

[image]

I am using VB6 here. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this,

Use Record Macro in Excel to record the steps you formatting in Excel. Then open the Macro you recorded in VBA. From there you should find the clues on how to do this in VB6.

Comment: That is new for me. I will explore that and will be back for the output. Thanks